# Проблема с итерацией в цикле

Tags: java, коллекции, foreach, for

Есть некоторая коллекция(исходник: [Проблема с удалением переменных классов потомков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1209277/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2)):

```
public class Manager {
    String place;
    String size;
    ArrayList<Thing> things;

public class Thing {
    String shelfPlace;                  //  Место на полке
    String thingSize;                      //  Размер вещи
```

Есть реализованный метод. Метод через **FOREACH**:

```
void delThing(String place, String size) {
    for (Thing thing : things) {
        if ((place.equals(thing.shelfPlace)) && (size.equals(thing.thingSize))) {
            things.remove(thing);
            System.out.println("Что-то там удалено");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Нет такого.");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

***ВОПРОС:*** **Как реализовать его через FORi ?**

Непонятно какая структура получится при выводе и шаг итерации.
Вот что есть:

```
    void delThing(String place, String size) {
    for (int i = things.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if ((place.equals(things.get(i))) && (size.equals(things.get(i)))) {       //непонятно что из себя представляет массив и с каким элекментом работатью.
            things.remove(things.get(i));
            System.out.println("Что-то там удалено");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Нет такого.");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

В попытке вывести код через sout, получил:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: arraycopy: element type mismatch: can not cast one of the elements of java.lang.Object[] to the type of the destination array, java.lang.String
at java.base/java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.toArray(ArrayList.java:401)
at ThingManager.Manager.delThing(Manager.java:40)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот перевод ошибки (вольный):

```
 element type mismatch: can not cast one of the elements of java.lang.Object[] to the type of the destination array, java.lang.String

несоответствуют типы: нельзя привести один из элементов массива к типу целевого массива
```

Если брать именно код который приводит к ошибке и разобрать его:

```
for (int i = things.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if ((place.equals(things.get(i))) && (size.equals(things.get(i)))) {  
            ....
    }
```

По поводу самого порядка перебора сказать ничего не могу, вам виднее как это делать. Я только укажу на проблему из-за которой походу все падает:

```
если(место(String).соответствует(массив объектов класса(Thing).взять(элемент i)) и размер(String).соответствует(массив объектов класса(Thing).взять(элемент i)))
```

то есть по факту вы пытаетесь сравнить класс со строкой, а это как-бы не очень правильно. В вашем массиве реализуйте взятие элемента из массива:

```
for (int i = things.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
Thing thing = things.get(i);
        if ((place.equals(thing.getshelfPlace())) && (size.equals(things.get thingSize()))) {  
            things.remove(things.get(i));
            System.out.println("Что-то там удалено");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Нет такого.");
            break;
        }
}
```

думаю после этого исправления ошибка пропадёт. И добавьте больше уточняющей информации в вопрос пожалуйста.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Геттеры уже есть в исходнике, просто я пока не понимаю тонкостей использования полей/методов классов/extendsКлассов.
Вы подсказали.
Все работает.